# Array - What's the best way to check a value exists in one of the array elements (React / JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So this is an example data array that I will get back from backend. There are a few use cases as shown below and I want to target based on the subscription values in the array.

Example: 1

```
const orgList = [
    { id: "1", orgName: "Organization 1", subscription: "free" },
    { id: "2", orgName: "Organization 2", subscription: "business" },
];
```

In the example 1 - when array comes back with this combination - there will be some styling and text to target the element with `subscription: free` to upgrade its subscription

Example 2:

```
const orgList = [
    { id: "1", orgName: "Organization 1a", subscription: "pro" },
    { id: "2", orgName: "Organization 2a", subscription: "business" },
];
```

Example 3:

```
const orgList = [
    { id: "1", orgName: "Organization 1b", subscription: "free" },
];
```

In the example 3 - when array comes back with only one element - there will be some styling and text to target the element say to upgrade its subscription

At the moment, I'm simply using map to go over the array that I get back like so:
`{orgList.map((org) => (...do something here)}` but with this I'm a bit limited as I don't think this is the best way to handle the 3 use cases / examples above.

Another idea is too do something like this before mapping but this:

`const freeSubAndBusinessSub = org.some(org => org.subscription === 'free' && org.subscription === "business")`

but doesn't seem to work as it returns `false` and then I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed after..

So my question is what's the best way to approach this kind of array to target what do to with the elements based on their values?

Comment: I think that `Array.map` is the best way to do what you want. During the map, you can have some logic to add styling for different subscription types. What made you think that it's limiting you?

Comment: I didnt get whats the problem with using a map function? isnt your problem about checking the subscription type? you could just loop over the array and check the subscription type (using an if statment or switch) and after that you decide what to do in each case. am i missing something ?

Comment: `org.subscription === 'free' && org.subscription === "business"` - how will `org.subscription` ever be both `'free'` and `'business'` simultaneously? Not sure what you are going for, but maybe you want to do `org.filter((o) => o.subscription === 'free' || o.subscription === 'business').map((o) => ...)`

Comment: I guess I'm not explaining well enough above..without overcomplicating it.. I guess there will be a use case when the array comes back with `[ {subscription: pro}, {subscription: business}] ` and if that's the case it means the user has the two top subscriptions under his account and therefore no upselling is happening so styling that targets to `pro` won't apply here. But if the arr comes back with only this `[ {subscription: pro}]` then I want to do something to suggest user should upgrade one up to business. I guess I just want to find an easier to handle different use cases like so.

Comment: In short, I guess I want to be able to filter the array first knowing what types of subscriptions are there in the array and then do the `map`

Comment: I have provided some examples on how to do that.  Your question does not sound like what you really want.  It sounds like you want to act based on the summary of the list data, rather than act on each item individually. Take a look at example 2 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that using `.map()` is limited, but you don't expand on it.  Logically what it sounds like you want is a separate list for each type to act upon.  You can accomplish this using `.filter()` or `.reduce()`, however, in this case `.map()` is your friend.

```js
// Example 1
const free = orgList.filter(org => org.subscription === 'free');
const business = orgList.filter(org => org.subscription === 'business');
free.map(org => /* do free stuff */);
business.map(org => /* do business stuff */);
```

```js
// Example 2
const subscriptions = orgList.reduce((all, cur) => {
  if (!all.hasOwnProperty(cur.subscription)) {
    all[cur.subscription] = [];
  }
  all[cur.subscription].push(cur);
  return all;
}, {});
subscriptions['free'].map(org => /* do free stuff */);
subscriptions['business'].map(org => /* do business stuff */);
```

```js
// Example 3
orgList.map(org => {
  switch(org.subscription) {
    case 'free':
      /* do free stuff */
    break;
    case 'business':
      /* do business stuff */
    break;
  }
})
```

You'll notice that in all the examples, you still need to map on the individual orgs to perform your actions.  Additionally, with the first two examples, you'll be touching each element more than once, which can be incredibly inefficient.  With a single `.map()` solution, you touch each element of the list only once.  If you feel that you `do free stuff` actions become unwieldy, you can separate them out in separate functions.